# What is my correct path to file in file manager for start node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, socket.io

What is my correct path to file in file manager for start node js ?

in putty in tried to start `node app.js`

But still show

```
Cannot find module '/root/app.js'
```

i create `app.js` in file manager (filezilla client), that can access to this file by url `example.com/app.js`

So i tried to use this `node srv/www/my ftp username/app.js`

but still error?

I want to know full path for app.js for start node js, how can i do ?

(i use `centos` and `vestacp`)

Answer (score 0):

> What is my correct path to file in file manager for start node js ?

It's wherever you put it in the file system.

> Cannot find module '/root/app.js'

Wherever you put it, it isn't in Root's home directory.

**Don't run software as root!**

> that can access to this file by url example.com/app.js

Don't expose your serverside code to the public on your webserver!

> So i tried to use this node srv/www/my ftp username/app.js but still error?

With what error?

Presumably, the `srv` directory isn't inside Root's home directory. You need to put the correct path to it. Possibly this would involve starting with `/`.

`my ftp username` has spaces in it, so if that is the *real* path (which seems unlikely), you would need to escape them.